# pandas groupby middle heading

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-science

How to group this data with pandas by heading in column `sl. no`
I have data like below in CSV or excel.

| sl. No | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `Heading1` |  |  |  |
| 1 | 243 | 45 | 3244 |
| 2 | 3 | 25 | 33 |
| 3 | 43 | 324 | 54 |
| `Head2` |  |  |  |
| 1 | 3 | 45 | 54 |
| 2 | 24 | 4 | 42 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Here is the dummy csv file

```
sl. No,v1,v2,v3,v4
Heading1,,,,
1,243,45,3244,
2,3,25,33,
3,43,324,54,
Head2,,,,
1,3,45,54,
2,24,4,42,
```

Comment: hi Hillal, can you copy and paste the csv first 5-10 lines in directly. It's unclear from your table if (for example) the `Heading1` row has any commas in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### By pattern

To group by string/pattern match, you can use a string operation ([`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html)/[`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)/…) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to increment a group number:

```
group = df['sl. No'].str.startswith('Head').cumsum()
```

Or, to get the original names combine with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
group = df['sl. No'].where(df['sl. No'].str.startswith('Head')).ffill()
```

---

##### By "type"

To identify the headings as non-integers, use a variant with [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
group = df['sl. No'].where(pd.to_numeric(df['sl. No'], errors='coerce').isna()).ffill()
```

To use the fact the other columns are empty/NaN, [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)/[`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html)/[`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)+[`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
group = df['v1'].isna().cumsum()
# or for empty strings
# group = df['v1'].eq('').cumsum()
```

Or:

```
group = df['sl. No'].where(df['v1'].isna()).ffill()
# or for empty strings
# group = df['sl. No'].where(df['v1'].eq('')).ffill()
```

Demo:

```
df.assign(group1 = df['sl. No'].str.startswith('Head').cumsum(),
          group2 = df['sl. No'].where(df['sl. No'].str.startswith('Head')).ffill(),
          group3 = df['sl. No'].where(pd.to_numeric(df['sl. No'], errors='coerce').isna()).ffill(),
          group4 = df['v1'].isna().cumsum(),
          group5 = df['sl. No'].where(df['v1'].isna()).ffill(),
         )

     sl. No     v1     v2      v3  v4  group1    group2    group3  group4    group5
0  Heading1    NaN    NaN     NaN NaN       1  Heading1  Heading1       1  Heading1
1         1  243.0   45.0  3244.0 NaN       1  Heading1  Heading1       1  Heading1
2         2    3.0   25.0    33.0 NaN       1  Heading1  Heading1       1  Heading1
3         3   43.0  324.0    54.0 NaN       1  Heading1  Heading1       1  Heading1
4     Head2    NaN    NaN     NaN NaN       2     Head2     Head2       2     Head2
5         1    3.0   45.0    54.0 NaN       2     Head2     Head2       2     Head2
6         2   24.0    4.0    42.0 NaN       2     Head2     Head2       2     Head2
```

Comment: By rushing to answer, see if you are doing this person a disservice.

Comment: @Сергей I don't think I rushed anything, I tried to provide the most possibilities to be helpful to future users. How is this not helpful?

Comment: This seems to me a comprehensive and didactic answer which facilitates using groupby or a multi-index.